# Does photo fingerprinting (using metadata) allow to search all photos on internet made by the same user (privacy issue)?

Tags: privacy, identity, confidentiality, fingerprinting

Browser fingerprinting is well-known: since a client gives many HTTP attributes/Javascript attributes during a website visit, the probability that two users have the same exact values for all this parameters is very low, and a user can sometimes be easily identified as unique (example: [amiunique.org](https://amiunique.org/fp)).

In a same fashion, **is there a risk (for one's privacy) that if someone shares a single photo somewhere on the web, then we can find all photos shared by the same person on internet?**

Indeed, photos metadata (EXIF) are sometimes present on photos that people upload to their website (people sometimes don't remove them), containing:

- name of the device (ok, many people in the world have the same device)
- maybe firmware version (then the number of people having the exact same version is lower) or OS version?
- sometimes geolocation
- other unique IDs?

Then won't using a service like images.google.com (or a similar tool which offer metadata advanced search) allow anyone to find all photos uploaded by the same user?

**More precisely: given a set of metadata coming from a photo, can people easily search all photos on internet made by the same device** (thus creating a privacy risk)? Or do major image search engines prevent this to happen (by rejecting metadata search)?

---

Example for a photo:

```
---- File ----
FileName                        : ...
Directory                       : ...
FileSize                        : ...
FileModifyDate                  : ...
FilePermissions                 : ...
FileType                        : JPEG
MIMEType                        : image/jpeg
ExifByteOrder                   : Little-endian (Intel, II)
ImageWidth                      : ...
ImageHeight                     : ...
EncodingProcess                 : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
BitsPerSample                   : 8
ColorComponents                 : 3
YCbCrSubSampling                : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
---- EXIF ----
ImageWidth                      : ...
ImageHeight                     : ...
Make                            : ...
Model                           : ...
Orientation                     : Rotate 180
XResolution                     : 72
YResolution                     : 72
ResolutionUnit                  : inches
Software                        : Ai0j1i567fs
ModifyDate                      : ...
YCbCrPositioning                : Centered
ExposureTime                    : ...
FNumber                         : ...
ExposureProgram                 : Program AE
ISO                             : ...
ExifVersion                     : 0220
DateTimeOriginal                : ...
CreateDate                      : ...
ComponentsConfiguration         : Y, Cb, Cr, -
ShutterSpeedValue               : 1/132
ApertureValue                   : ...
BrightnessValue                 : ...
ExposureCompensation            : 0
MaxApertureValue                : ...
MeteringMode                    : Center-weighted average
LightSource                     : Unknown
Flash                           : Fired
FocalLength                     : ...
UserComment                     : ...
FlashpixVersion                 : 0100
ColorSpace                      : sRGB
ExifImageWidth                  : ...
ExifImageHeight                 : ...
InteropIndex                    : R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
InteropVersion                  : 0100
SensingMethod                   : One-chip color area
SceneType                       : Directly photographed
ExposureMode                    : Auto
WhiteBalance                    : Auto
FocalLengthIn35mmFormat         : 31 mm
SceneCaptureType                : Standard
ImageUniqueID                   : H07RA02XP
GPSVersionID                    : 2.2.0.0
ImageWidth                      : 512
ImageHeight                     : 288
Compression                     : JPEG (old-style)
Orientation                     : Rotate 180
XResolution                     : 72
YResolution                     : 72
ResolutionUnit                  : inches
ThumbnailOffset                 : ...
ThumbnailLength                 : ...
---- MakerNotes ----
MakerNoteVersion                : 0100
```

Comment: I googled "fingerprinting camera from metadata" and got quite a number of high quality hits

Comment: one of which is: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16777/how-can-i-tell-if-two-pictures-were-taken-with-the-same-camera-without-metadata

Comment: @schroeder So did I, I found articles like https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2006/04/digital_cameras.html, but the ones I found mostly did not cover the risk of search the whole web for all photos made by a single user. I will update the title accordingly, thank you for your comment.

Comment: "search" is a completely different issue from fingerprinting. How are you relating them?

Comment: @schroeder "Search" is not an issue. The issue is the lack of privacy, and the mix of fingerprinting + search creates this issue.

Comment: Privacy is your *concern* that emerges from the details. Your focus in your question is a mash up of various details. ***If*** the metadata survives, it can be searched. ***If*** the image maintains the hardware signature in uploaded images, it can be searched. But these are all obvious. And you say that you have researched these things. So, what is your question?

Comment: Can searches for these things be done at scale? How to search? What Google Dork to use?

Comment: Thank you for your comments @schroeder, I updated and added precision to the question.

Comment: So your question is about search engines? Because anyone can crawl the internet for images.

Comment: @Basj: I think you are contradicting yourself in your question: in the title you ask if it is __possible at all__, then you ask if this is __easily possible__ and then you ask about what __major search engines__ might to against it. Also, you implicitly assume that all photos made by the same person will have publicly accessible metadata in the first place and that no cleanup is done by the user or by photo sharing services.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich "Possible at all": of course everyone can write an web scraper for images, build an infrastructure with a lot of servers, invest time and money to be able to search in this gigantic database and at the end have a service similar to images.google.com. But very few people will do it, so my question is: if a random person (not NSA, no gouv agency, not a multinational company) wants to find all photos made by someone, is it possible (without investing months creating a worldwide image scraper)? If so, it is indeed an immediate privacy concern.

Comment: 2/2 If it requires building a worldwide scraper to do this search, the concern is less significant as of today.

Comment: @Basj: again, you are implying that all the images a) can be found by a crawler at the first place and b) still have their meta data in place. But many services actually remove the meta data - see https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/exif-privacy/13356/ for details.